# How to get list of selected OpportunityLineItem ids List Button VF - Salesforce Lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, list-button

We are migrating our development from Salesforce Classic to Salesforce Lightning.

In Salesforce Classic having a development 'Mass Update' opportunity line item from Opportuntiy.

Having custom list On click Java Script button 'Mass Update'which will get selected `OpportunityLineItem` record ids to update  using

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem)};
```

and selected values will be passed to VF Page. This works fine Salesforce Classic.

How can I get selected OpportunityLineItem record ids from related list on custom list buttom (VF Page)?

We tried by using `StandardSetController` but `StandardSetController` can't be used for `OpportunityLineItem`.

Answer (score 0):

The migration of this javascript button isn't possible, my suggestion is to create a component (Aura or LWC) or screen flow as a quick action in the Opportunity object with a pre-step in which you can choose the opportunity line items and after this execute your logic with the items selected.